# Clearly SQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
IF @Active=0
    select @rowCount=(select count(1) from [table] WHERE (GETDATE() BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime) AND Active=@Active 

IF @Active=1
    select @rowCount=(select count(1) from [table] WHERE NOT(GETDATE() BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime) AND Active=@Active
```

Is there any way to make the statements more clear?

I'm doing pagination like this:

Parameters:

```
@pageNum    AS BIGINT,
@pageSize   AS BIGINT,
@Active AS INT,
@RowCount   AS INT OUTPUT
```

And the Rest:

```
IF @Active=0
BEGIN
    WITH K AS 
    (    - SELECT [Id]
      FROM [table]
      WHERE not(GETDATE() BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime) AND    Active=@Active  ORDER BY [Id]
      OFFSET (@pagenum - 1) * @pagesize ROWS FETCH NEXT @pagesize ROWS ONLY
    )
    SELECT T.[Id],T.[Name]
    FROM [table]
     AS T 
      INNER JOIN K
        ON T.Id = K.Id

    ORDER BY T.Id;

    select @rowCount=(select count(1) from [table] WHERE not(GETDATE() BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime) AND   Active=@Active
END
IF @Active=1
BEGIN
    WITH K AS 
    (    
      SELECT [Id]
      FROM [table]
      WHERE (GETDATE() BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime) AND    Active=@Active
      ORDER BY [Id]
      OFFSET (@pagenum - 1) * @pagesize ROWS FETCH NEXT @pagesize ROWS ONLY
    )
    SELECT T.[Id],T.[Name]
    FROM [table]
     AS F 
      INNER JOIN K
        ON T.Id = K.Id

    ORDER BY T.Id;

    select @rowCount=(select count(1) from [table] WHERE (GETDATE() BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime) AND  Active=@Active  END
```

and the stored procedure looks very long.....
so I'm wondering is there better way to make it better

Comment: Are the two possible counts meant to be exhaustive - i.e. is it meant to be that if you call this once with `@Active` set to 0, and again with it set to 1, and add the results together, should the sum of those two results be the same as `select COUNT(*) from [table]`? Because at the moment, that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

This might be clearer and involves only one SELECT:

```
select @rowcount = case @active 
    when 0 then sum(case when GETDATE() BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime then 1 else 0 end)
    when 1 then sum(case when GETDATE() BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime then 0 else 1 end) end
from [table]
where Active=@Active
```

Or this suggestion from @Damien_The_Unbeliever is even pithier (although perhaps less clear!):

```
select @rowcount = sum(case when GETDATE() BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime then 1-@Active else 0+@active end)
from [table]
where Active=@Active
```

Comment: May be able to collapse this by using `1-@active` and `0+@active` as the two expressions for the inner `case`.

Comment: Thanks - have added your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
   IF @Active=0 select @rowCount=(SELECT CASE 
   WHEN @Active=0 
      THEN select count(1) from [table] WHERE (GETDATE() BETWEEN StartTime AND  EndTime) AND Active=@Active
   WHEN @Active=1 
      THEN  select count(1) from [table] WHERE NOT(GETDATE() BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime)  AND Active=@Active
```

can you make your question more clear ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is clearer but here's another method that's slightly less verbose:

```
SELECT @rowCount = COUNT(1)
FROM [table] 
WHERE
    ((GETDATE() BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime) AND Active = @Active) 
    OR (NOT (GETDATE() BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime) AND Active = @Active);
```